# 'req.params.id' is only accessed by first two middleware functions, but not the third. Why?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, middleware

Here is the code snippet in index.js:

```
const { loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser } = require("./middlewares/auth");
const tasks = require("./routes/task");

app.use("/api/tasks/:id", loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser, tasks);
```

Here, only `loginRequired` and `ensureCorrectUser` can access the `:id`, but `tasks` can't...

Here is the code snippet from the router:

```
const { getTasks, addTask } = require("../handlers/task");
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").get(getTasks).post(addTask);

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js:

```
exports.loginRequired = function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function (err, decoded) {
      if (decoded) {
        return next();
      } else {
        return next({
          status: 401,
          message: "Please login first",
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next({
      status: 401,
      message: "Please login first",
    });
  }
};

exports.ensureCorrectUser = function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function (err, decoded) {
      if (decoded && decoded.id === req.params.id) {
        console.log(req.params.id); //prints correct id
        return next();
      } else {
        return next({
          status: 401,
          message: "Unauthorized!",
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next({
      status: 401,
      message: "Unauthorized!",
    });
  }
};
```

handler snippet:

```
exports.getTasks = async function (req, res, next) {
  await db.User.findById(req.params.id)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(req.params); //prints empty object
      res.status(200).json([...data.tasks]);
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};

exports.addTask = async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let user = await db.User.findById(req.params.id);
    console.log(req.params); //prints empty object
    user.tasks.push(req.body);
    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Task Added!" });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Why is it so..? Please help..

Comment: can you attach loginRequired and ensureCorrectUser?

Comment: Added.. Please Review..

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked finally. But it's quite messy.

```
router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser, getTasks)
  .post(loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser, addTask);
router.delete("/id/:id2", loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser, removeTask);
router.post("/id/complete/:id2", loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser, setComplete);
```